# CSS Div getting out of the viewport and ruining the responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

As a homework for school I'm creating a website but a div
`.container {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70vw;
    width: 100vw;
}` 
is getting out the window, because of this the h1
`.titolo {
    font-family: musei;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`
put inside it makes the h1 and a 
form
`.map {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}` 
put inside the div aswell, not centered on all resolutions.

Why doesn't the div is a little bit larger instead of taking the excat width of the window even if i wrote 100vw?

Here's the full HTML/CSS code

```css
.immag {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.map {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.titolo {
    font-family: musei;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70vw;
    width: 100vw;
}

.border {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: #00c4ff;
    border-width: 1vw; 
    width: 20vw;
    height: auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: musei;
    src: url(font-titolo-musei.otf);
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.over {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 200vw;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
        <title>1CE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="Senza%20titolo-1.jpg" class="immag">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="border">
        <h1 class="titolo">MUSEI</h1>
            </div><br>
        <iframe class="map" src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zi8GElmpTlNo.kJ3GnRl1X08c" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 100vw will always make the site take up the entire viewport, however a scrollbar is also part of the viewport and will make what is displayed smaller than the actual viewport. using width:100% will solve your problem with the scrollbar being in the way.